# Adding more server routes to "ng serve"

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm writing an application that has both server and front-end code, and I'm using the angular cli with NG serve.

I don't want to run another web server for my server-side API in dev, I would like to use the existing web server that angular uses when I'm running "ng serve"

How do I register customer server routes to the web server used by "ng serve"

I'm not sure it's relevant but here is the package json:

```
{
  "name": "test-ng-forms",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
```

}

Comment: `ng serve ` is develop command , you really want to do that?

Comment: what is your server side language?

Comment: please add your package.json file and what is your server side language?

Comment: @RachChen yes - I want that in development to simplify my work

Comment: @RoweldeGuzman typescript

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd the language of my server is typescript as well - I'm using express for now.

The package json is the default one that is created with ng new command

Comment: could you share package.json file here

Comment: I would recommend set the CI(yml) file and it would be easily to found source.

Comment: @RachChen - I'm sorry but I don't know how to do what you've said :)

Comment: @Noam I would make the new CI way to you,but it’s not the simplify method truly lol